# Telephone number showing on website, but not showing up on mobile

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a php driven website, and one of the data blocks is telephone number, however, it is showing on the web, and the bootstrap site responds to mobile devices showing correctly.  However the number, and only the number, doesn't show up.

See http://www.airfieldcards.com/bootstrap_site/index.php?a=e&f=164

Viewed on the web, you can see the bottom entry, PPR number (a telephone number)

Try it on a mobile phone, and there's nothing in the box displayed.

Comment: There are two sections in the code, one for mobile and one for desktop. They have different information in each, which is why you're seeing the difference between mobile and desktop - in terms of a fix you'll need to simply add the missing content into both tables

Comment: Yes, there are two sections, one for mobile and one for desktop, however, when I shrink my desktop to mobile size, (and therefore get the mobile version) the PPR number is there.  But when I view it on the mobile (iphone 5s) it is not.

Answer (score 0):

PPR number shows up. Be sure to fix your bootstrap grid; separate **.container** elements and don't have **.containers** inside **.row**. It produces an overflow of the document element to the right when your on mobile view.

Current HTML code;

```
<div class="container" id="container1">
 <div class="row" id="row1">

  <div class="container" id="container2">
   <div class="row" id="row2"></div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Should be (with additional markup);

```
<div class="container" id="container1">
 <div class="row" id="row1">
  <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row" id="row2">
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this for larger devices...
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 invisible-xs invisible-sm visible-md      visible-lg">

And this for Small...
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs visible-sm invisible-md      invisible-lg">

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the reason it wasn't showing up was because I had links set to "white" and because it was a link on a phone (being a telephone number) it looked like it didn't show up.  However, when I changed the CSS I got it to show up.

Doh...